# Task not serializable : Caused by java.io.NotSerializableException org.apache.spark.SparkConf

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

i'm trying to exploit some data from Cassandra database using the spark cassandra connector but i'm falling on this error :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
.
.
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkConf
```

You can see my code below, i'm using the spark-shell for the experiments

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._, org.apache.spark.SparkContext, 
org.apache.spark.SparkContext._, org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import collection.JavaConverters._


sc.stop
val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
val sc = new SparkContext("local","test",conf)

val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("key", "table_name")
rdd.collect // ok
val rdd2 = rdd.where("aa > 10 and aa < 20")
rdd2.collect  // ok
// method1 return an object without any link with SparkContext
val rdd3 = rdd2.map( x=> method1() )
rdd3.collect   // ok
// Error rise to get rdd4
val rdd4 = rdd3.map(x=>method2(x,new Obj1(x.method3())))
// If i do that it works
rdd3.collect.map(x=>method2(x,new Obj1(x.method3())))
```

I read some case where user called method including SparkContext as parameter inside a map function but that's not my case. The objects on which i called method are object without any link with SparkContext.

I tried to collect rdd rdd2 rdd3 with success but when i apply the map to get rdd4 i fall on the error.

Comment: Looks like either `method2`, `method3`, or `Obj1` contains an instance of `SparkConf`, which is not serializable.

Comment: Is there any other options because Obj1 method2/3 are writen in pure Java without any reference to SparkContext...

Comment: I'm afraid the problem has to be in one of those, since there are no other references in your `map` function. I would guess the problem is in `Obj1` since functions should be serializable. You could try to use a mixin, i.e. `val rdd4 = rdd3.map(x=>method2(x,new Obj1(x.method3()) with Serializable ))`

Comment: Sometimes you can get weird linkages in the shell too. Things can become part of the object graph of functions you don't want. Usually the spark-shell is pretty good at cleaning these but sometimes you still can have issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and solved by removing the line `val sc = new SparkContext` because I use Apache Zeppelin and it provides an `sc` by default.

Try put the `sc.stop` at the end of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve the issue, in fact i had arguments of method2 which were declared locally.

```
val v1 = Set[Double].empty.asJava
val v2 = java.lang.Boolean.TRUE
```

I just broadcast this values and all works like a charm.
Thank you for your advices